# Como mandar múltiplas requests ao mesmo tempo

Tags: python, thread, request

Bom meu programa pega URLs de um arquivo de texto, entra nelas e verifica se tem um determinado texto em seu código HTML, seria possível ler todas as linhas do arquivo, e ao invés de fazer uma *request* por vez, faz todas de uma vez só?

Answer (score 3):

De forma assíncrona?

Se sim, uma forma de fazer isso é usar o [`grequests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grequests) para fazer as requisições. Para instalar, no terminal digite:

```
pip install grequests
```

Você pode usá-lo assim (adaptado da [documentação](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests#usage)):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import grequests 

urls = [
    'https://www.python.org/',
    'https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grequests',
    'http://pt.stackoverflow.com/'
]

requisicoes = (grequests.get(url) for url in urls)
mp = grequests.map(requisicoes)

for request in mp:
    print ("{}: {}".format(request.status_code, request.url))
    #(print request.content)
```

Para implementar [cookies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies) com `grequests`, faça assim:

```
sessao = grequests.Session()
cookies = { 'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'bar' }

requisicao = sessao.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies', cookies = cookies)

print ("{}: {}".format(requisicao.status_code, requisicao.url))
print (requisicao.text)
```

<sub>A lógica é a mesma para o `requests`.</sub>

### Python 3.2+

Se estiver usando Python *>= 3.2*, o módulo [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#) pode vir a ser útil para fazer uma tarefa de forma assíncrona. O exemplo abaixo usa o [`requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) para fazer as requisições.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import requests

def get(url, timeout):
    return requests.get(url, timeout = timeout)

def requestUrls(urls, timeout = 5):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 5) as executor:
        agenda = { executor.submit(get, url, timeout): url for url in urls }

        for tarefa in as_completed(agenda):     
            try:
                conteudo = tarefa.result()
            except Exception as e:
                print ("Não foi possível fazer a requisição! \n{}".format(e))
            else:
                yield conteudo
```

O número de *threads* é definido em `max_workers`, se for omitido ou `None`, o padrão é o número de processadores na máquina. <sup>[Fonte](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor)</sup>

Use assim:

```
urls = [
    'https://www.python.org/',
    'https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests',
    'http://pt.stackoverflow.com/',
]

requisicoes = requestUrls(urls) # timeout é opcional, o padrão é 5

for requisicao in requisicoes:
    codigo = requisicao.status_code
    url = requisicao.url
    conteudo = requisicao.content

    print ("{}: {}".format(codigo, url))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por me responder, mas no caso do grequest como q faço para utilizar cookies(PHPSESSID)?

Comment: @LeonardoJulio Foi colocado um exemplo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda!! estou testando

Comment: @LeonardoJulio Ok, qualquer coisa só avisar